# soundcloud open buy link in _self

Tags: soundcloud

I've embedded the HTML5 player on my wordpress website. All my songs contain BUY links on soundcloud that link to my song page but right now it opens all buy links in target="_blank" but is it possible to change this to target="_self" ?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not possible to change this.